# reset to main loop doesnt work

Tags: wp-query, loop, wp-reset-postdata

I open the administration page for my custom post type.
So the url is:

> wp-admin/post.php?post=39&action=edit

When I do the following Code, the output is of course 39:

```
<?php
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
?>
```

Now I added a new WP_Query and loop over the result, because I need Data from another post.

```
<?php
global $post;
echo $post->ID.", ";
$args = array('post_type' => 'xyz');
$loop = new WP_Query($args); 
if(!is_null($loop) && $loop->have_posts()) {
    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 
        echo get_the_ID().", ";
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
echo $post->ID;
?>
```

After that Code the output is: 39, 40, 39, 8, 8

But I expected: 39, 40, 39, 8, **39**

I thought `wp_reset_postdata()` would set the global $post to the main query? Why is it still the last post from my WP_Query?

Or have I completly misunderstoodthe function of wp_reset_postdata();

EDIT:
In the documentation (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
I found this:

> Note: Ticket #18408 For querying posts in the admin, consider using
>   get_posts() as wp_reset_postdata() might not behave as expected.

So it seems to be "normal".
But what is the best practice if I shouldnt use WP_Query in the admin?
For now I store the global $post in a local variable and set the global $post back to the old value after my query.

```
<?php
global $post;
$tempPost = $post;
echo $post->ID.", ";
$args = array('post_type' => 'xyz');
$loop = new WP_Query($args); 
if(!is_null($loop) && $loop->have_posts()) {
    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 
        echo get_the_ID().", ";
    endwhile;
}
$post = $tempPost;
echo $post->ID;
?>
```

But this solution doesn't feels right

Comment: Where are you putting this code? Are you using a hook such as admin_init?

Comment: Have you also tried with adding wp_reset_query() after the reset?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the admin_init hook. E.g. I hook also in a *add_form_fields hook with this.

And yes, I have tried wp_reset_query().